# GetKeyboardLayout() doesn't change when switching between ENG US and ENG INT

Tags: c++, winapi

This is for an app running on Windows 10. I have two keyboard layouts loaded,  `ENG US` and `ENG INT`

I am using `GetKeyboardLayout(0)` however I get the same result regardless of which layout I'm using.

How can I detect which of the two keyboard layouts are in use?

This maybe my mistake, if I make the call like

`GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(::GetForegroundWindow(), 0))`

Then I get the correct result each time. Now I'm confused because I was under the impression that the keyboard layout was global on Windows 10.

Comment: It's not global, pretty sure it isn't global since at least Windows XP, definitively not global since 7.

Answer (score 0):

[Languages, Locales, and Keyboard Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#languages-locales-and-keyboard-layouts):

> Applications typically use locales to set the language in which input
>   and output is processed. Setting the locale for the keyboard, for
>   example, affects the character values generated by the keyboard.
>   Setting the locale for the display or printer affects the glyphs
>   displayed or printed. Applications set the locale for a keyboard by
>   loading and using keyboard layouts. They set the locale for a display
>   or printer by selecting a font that supports the specified locale.
>
> Applications are generally not expected to manipulate input languages
>   directly. Instead, the user sets up language and layout combinations,
>   then switches among them.

Calls the [`ActivateKeyboardLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-activatekeyboardlayout) function to activate the user's default layout for that language.

Calls the [`GetKeyboardLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout) function to get layout.

Both are thread-based or process-based.

I guess what you might want to get is the input locale identifier for the system default input language, which is global.

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, 0, &hkl, 0);
```